# my windows 8 doesn't reconize any new device via usb, is there a way to remove all drivers on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers

Anytime that i plug in any USB device (mobile phone, printer, usb wifi stick, headphones..) on my pc, Win8 Pro x64 not reconized, is installed as "Unknow Device",

going to Manage-> Device Manager, and uninstall the device , sometimes is reconized after several attempts , but i have to be lucky,

if i restart the pc, it reconized , so i was wondering if removing all the drivers of the machine, and then windows restoring all those drivers,should fix the problem?

or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Obvious question, but does this happen with all USB ports?

Comment: yeap, it happends in any USB port, i tried all of them

Comment: Have you installed the USB drivers for your motherboard?

Comment: yeap, and nothing and after i tried with a software called "slimdrivers" to update all the drivers, but not luck too

Comment: It's generally not advisable to use third-party applications that claim to install the drivers for you. I'm guessing that made your problems worse. You should clean/wipe the drivers using something like `DriverSweeper` and then install them from official sources.

Comment: i just tried with DriverSweeper as you suggested but sadly is only detects drivers related with Graphics Card and Audio

Comment: That suggests you don't have the official USB drivers installed. You need to find the official drivers for your motherboard.

Comment: i had installed all official drivers of my motherboard, but it seems that application is design just to remove graphics/audio drivers

Comment: On my PC, DriverSweeper picks up all of my drivers (including USB) as far as I can tell.

Comment: could be that maybe your motherboard used nvidia chipset?, mine is Intel

Comment: No, my motherboard doesn't use an Nvidia chipset. Nvidia is a graphics card manufacturer and I don't know of any motherboards that have an Nvidia chipset. Most motherboards nowadays either run on an Intel (including mine) or AMD chipset.